# Running function in FastAPI view while returning an HTTP response without waiting for the function to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have the following code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
import uvicorn
from testphoto.utils.logger import get_log
import datetime
import time
import asyncio

log = get_log()

app = FastAPI()

def process():
    log.info("Sleeping at "+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    time.sleep(5)
    log.info("Woke up at "+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    return "Sucess"

@app.post("/api/photos")
async def root(request: Request, photo: str = Form()):
    process()
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8008)
```

What I want to do is to run the function `process` and return the response while keeping the function `process` running. I've read some documentation about asyncio and FastAPI but I'm still unable to figure this out. Where would you point me to in order make the code do exactly as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for, if not CPU intensive, is called a background task.

You can read more in the docs:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/

An example [from the reference guide on how to use background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#using-backgroundtasks):

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


def write_notification(email: str, message=""):
    with open("log.txt", mode="w") as email_file:
        content = f"notification for {email}: {message}"
        email_file.write(content)


@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, email, message="some notification")
    return {"message": "Notification sent in the background"}
```

Comment: Always include the relevant part from the source when posting an answer - a linked source can disappear at any moment or be replaced with a new URL.